# How to convert the Non-Monday column to Monday in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, data-science

I want to write a function that if a date is Tue.Wed.Tur. then convert it as this week's Monday, if a date is  Fri. Sat. Sun. then convert it as next week's Monday. If its a Monday, just leave as it is.

The example input Dataframe is like this:

| Model# | Order Category | 2022/4/18 | 2022/5/10 | 2022/5/18 | 2022/5/26 | 2022/6/24 | 2022/7/16 | 2022/7/24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Open | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | Close | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| C | Open | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

The ideal output is like this:

All the date headers are converted to Monday based on the rules I specified.

| Model# | Order Category | 2022/4/18 | 2022/5/9 | 2022/5/16 | 2022/5/23 | 2022/6/27 | 2022/7/18 | 2022/7/25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Open | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | Close | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| C | Open | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

# Convert as datetime and extract day of week
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[2:])
dow = dates.day_of_week

# Create timedelta Mon, Thu, Wed, Thu are negative, Fri, Sat, Sun are positive
offsets = pd.to_timedelta(np.where(dow < 4, -dow, 7-dow), unit='D')

# Adjust the dates then reindex your columns
dates = (dates + offsets).strftime('%Y/%-m/%-d')
df.columns = df.columns[:2].append(dates)
```

Output:

| Model# | Order Category | 2022/4/18 | 2022/5/9 | 2022/5/16 | 2022/5/23 | 2022/6/27 | 2022/7/18 | 2022/7/25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Open | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| B | Close | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| C | Open | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Intermediates:

| Before | Offset | After |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-18 | 0 days | 2022-04-18 |
| 2022-05-10 | -1 days | 2022-05-09 |
| 2022-05-18 | -2 days | 2022-05-16 |
| 2022-05-26 | -3 days | 2022-05-23 |
| 2022-06-24 | 3 days | 2022-06-27 |
| 2022-07-16 | 2 days | 2022-07-18 |
| 2022-07-24 | 1 days | 2022-07-25 |

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Model#': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'},
 'Order Category': {0: 'Open', 1: 'Close', 2: 'Open'},
 '2022/4/18': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 '2022/5/10': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 '2022/5/18': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 '2022/5/26': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1},
 '2022/6/24': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0},
 '2022/7/16': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1},
 '2022/7/24': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Step1**

Create data only for the date part by changing the date part to monday

```
idx = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns[2:], errors='coerce').to_period('W').to_timestamp()
```

idx

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-04-18', '2022-05-09', '2022-05-16', '2022-05-23',
               '2022-06-20', '2022-07-11', '2022-07-18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

---

**Step2**

make monday index

```
(df1
 .set_index(['Model#', 'Order Category'])
 .set_axis(idx.astype('str'), axis=1)
 .reset_index())
```

output:

```
Model#  Order Category  2022-04-18  2022-05-09  2022-05-16  2022-05-23  2022-06-20  2022-07-11  2022-07-18
0   A   Open            0           0           0           0           1           1           2
1   B   Close           1           1           0           0           1           2           2
2   C   Open            0           0           1           1           0           1           2
```

Comment: Fantastic! Perfectly works!